# What's the difference between myFunction.property and this.property?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, this

**Note: This is not a duplicate, the duplicate mentioned does not even remotely mention the same function. Plus this also refers to how angularjs works.**

So in angularjs, I recently had to make a controller and then inject data.

I am wondering why I had to do this:

```
function myController ($window) {
    var ctrl = this;
    return ctrl;
}
myController.$inject = ['$window'];
```

why can't I do this instead? What's the difference between the two?

```
function myController ($window) {
    var ctrl = this;
    ctrl.$inject = ['$window'];
    return ctrl;
}
```

Comment: Because `ctrl != myController`.

Comment: In the second example `this` points to a new created object with `myController` constructor function. But `$inject` has to be a static property of it.

Comment: Oh I see, the prototype! I completely forgot about that. If you post this as an answer I'll accept it.